# How to do a specific proccess per in month in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write a website and now I need to do a specific method one per month(at the end of the every month).

Imagine that the method is `Method A()`.

I want to run it at the end of the every month.

So now how to run it ?

**UPDATE:**

The mission of the website is something else.Just in a part of it I need to do this.

I dont know but I guess maybe running the method in application start at the end of the every month can solve it but I am not sure that its the way or not.

Comment: What is the reason to use a website to do this? Why not a Scheduled Task, Windows Service or SQL Job for instance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? There are lots of ways of doing this, the most widely used being a scheduled task or writing a window service that executes this method for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is for writing web applications, not scheduled tasks.

Web applications are architected as request/response systems.  They are not suited for background tasks which need to happen at regular intervals.  They receive a request, respond to that request, and are done.  While idle a web application is subject to the web server's resource management, which could include shutting it down entirely while waiting for the next request.

Instead, what you'll want to use is either a Windows Service or a Console Application (invoked by a task scheduler, such as the one that comes with Windows).  This would run continuously in the background or at regular intervals, respectively.  This application can be very small, just calling that one method and nothing else.

In short... If you want to run the code in response to a user request then a web application will do the job.  If you want to run the code at regular intervals regardless of user requests then a scheduled task is what you want.

Comment: Yes of course you are right.I should write and run a service on my host.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that seems like something that doesn't belong on the web site. i.e. it shouldn't be run within ASP.NET anywhere. Maybe it should be run in a back office, or a service that's running on the back end or a database job or a scheduled task. But if all you have is the one job, it would probably be easier to have a button that when pushed calls the method A(), and have it in a logged in portion of the website with some sort rights check to ensure no one but the correct people press it. And you could also put checks, within the method to ensure it's only run once a month. If you can be sure that the rest of the website is being used, you could put in other methods a CheckToSeeIfIShouldCallMethodA method, but all of these seem like worse options than something that runs on the back end.